# Selecting positions with querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, element

So the below selects all elements with the `<p>` tag

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');
```

and this selects the first `<p>` element

```
document.querySelector("p")
```

and this selects the third `<p>` element

```
document.querySelectorAll("p")[2]
```

If I have a document with 25 paragraphs how do I select paragraphs 5-13?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("p").slice(4,13)`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a for loop to select everything between `x` and `y`.

```
var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(i=5; i<14; i++) {
    paragraphs[i].style.color = 'tomato';
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/LnmdpLa4/

Not the most elegant solution, but it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var p = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 5 - 1, 13)
```

### Demo Snippet:

```js
var p = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 5 - 1, 13)

console.log(p)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>16</p>
<p>17</p>
<p>18</p>
<p>19</p>
<p>20</p>
<p>21</p>
<p>22</p>
<p>23</p>
<p>24</p>
<p>25</p>
```